# Convert Json to Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have interface items.ts:

```
export interface item{
  Name: string;
  IsSystemItem: string;
  ConfiguredSegments: ConfiguredSegments; 
}

export interface ConfiguredSegments {
  LiveA: LiveA;
}

export interface LiveA {
  Weight: number;
  Id: string;
}
```

I have a class where i am filling an array of items mockitems.ts :

```
export const items: item[] = [
  {
    Name: "Default Item",
    IsSystemItem: "yes",
    ConfiguredSegments: ConfiguredSegments.LiveA   // Here it is throwing error "Cannot find name 
                                                       ConfiguredSegments"
  }
]
```

How to fill ConfiguredSegments field ?

Comment: What do you intend to do with `ConfiguredSegments: ConfiguredSegments.LiveA`? What pbject would the property  `ConfiguredSegments` hold after?

Comment: Just realized we cannot use it as a value. Still learning @Mike S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConfiguredSegments` is an interface and not an object so you can not use it as a value. So you need to do

```
export const items: item[] = [
  {
    Name: "Default Item",
    IsSystemItem: "yes",
    ConfiguredSegments: {
       LiveA: {
           Weight: 123,
           Id: 'yourId'
       }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export const items: item[] = [
 {
    Name: "Default Item",
    IsSystemItem: "yes",
    ConfiguredSegments: {
        LiveA: {
            Weight: 0,
            Id: 'test id'
        }
    }
 }
]
```